# Як правильно українською перекласти "supervised/unsupervised learnning" (напрямок - "Машинне навчання")

Tags: переклад, from-english

Підкажіть як правильно перекласти "supervised/unsupervised learnning". це з напрямку "Machine learning" (машинне навчання). 
Знайшов [тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), але можливо є ще варіанти.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Згідно курсу лекцій](http://victoria.lviv.ua/html/neural_nets/Lecture2.htm#Control_navchannja) про нейронні мережі, краще всього використовувати термін "контрольоване" та "неконтрольоване" навчання. За посиланням сторінка, проте у неї кодування не UTF-8, а, здається, win-1251

> Контрольоване навчання
>
> Величезна більшість рішень отримана від нейромереж з контрольованим
>   навчанням, де біжучий вихід постійно порівнюється з бажаним виходом.
>   Ваги на початку встановлюються випадково, але під час наступних
>   ітерації коректуються для досягнення близької відповідності між
>   бажаним та біжучим виходом. Створені методи навчання націлені на
>   мінімізації біжучих похибок всіх елементів обробки, яке створюється за
>   якийсь час неперервною зміною синаптичних ваг до досягнення прийнятної
>   точності мережі.

Answer (score 9):

«Навчання з вчителем» / «Навчання без вчителя»

1. https://courses.prometheus.org.ua/courses/IRF/ML101/2016_T3/about
2. http://mooc.in.ua/catalog-item/machine-learning
3. Також такий переклад прийнятий [в російській традиції машинного навчання](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Answer (score 1):

Контрольоване навчання ще можна називати - навчання на прецедентах.
Знаходив про це в російській академічній літературі.
По суті самого навчання, то supervised leaning здійснюється на основі прецедентів - вже готової бази даних.

Також стикався з даним питанням, коли перекладав статтю з машинного навчання - [тут](https://rmalkevy.github.io/2017/02/18/Machine_Learning_is_fan/).