# Чи існує український відповідник «курировать»?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

*«Курировать»* та *«курированный»* можна перекласти як *«контрольований»* [[1]](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/137/117), або ж *«модерований»*.

Проте ці слова також мають російські відповідники *«контролировать»* та *«модерировать»*, тож *«курировать»* має певну семантичну відмінність від цих двох варіантів. Чи є відповідник в Українській мові який би точно передавав цю особливість?

Comment: Словники надають декілька варіантів перекладу, [ось наприклад](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on). А загалом, навряд чи вам дадуть відповідь на таке запитання, бо незрозуміло контекст у якому вам потрібно перекласти це слово.

Comment: Додам, що слово _курувати_ [в нових словниках є](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=46294&page=1461) (як і аналогічні слова, наприклад _куратор_; обидва слова прийшли з латини і не є прерогативою саме російської мови).

Comment: (Загалом, мені здається, із цих двох коментарів можна зробити й відповідь, мовляв, слово є і синоніми є.)

Comment: Раджу звернути увагу нп. на: ["Котування", "котирування", "квотування" - як правильно?](/q/3911/585) і [Чому "лідер", але "лідирувати", "лідирує"? Ріже вухо](/q/2650/585)